# Canon 300mm f2.8 IS Tripod collar ring mount

Tags: lens, canon

The tripod mount of my Canon 300mm f2.8 with IS is damaged. The original collar has a P/N of YG9-0618. I have searched for a replacement to no avail. There are 'Canon Tripod Mount Rings A/B/C' will any of these fit this particular lens?

The Canon Tripod Ring B(B) (black) looks extremely similar. The original has a ID of 88mm and has an internal groove that 4 'runners' sit in with 4 grooves to allow the ring to be mounted.

Comment: Please confirm that the lens in question is the EF 300mm f/2.8 L IS (or whatever *exact* model name published by Canon it is that you have).

Answer (score 1):

The *Tripod Mount Ring B* would be too small for your EF 300mm F/2.8 L IS lens. It is made to fit the MP-E 65mm f/2.8 1-5x Macro, EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro, and EF 180mm f/3.5L Macro among other lenses.

My EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II uses the white version of the *Tripod Mount Ring B* which has an inside diameter of 78mm.

*Tripod Mount Ring A* (EF 70-200mm f/4 L IS and EF 70-200mm f/4 L, EF 200mm f/2.8 L II) is even smaller than *Tripod Mount Ring B*.

*Tripod Mount Ring C* (EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 L) has an inner diameter of 82mm.
*Tripod Mount Ring D* (EF 100mm f/2.8 L Macro) is even smaller than *Tripod Ring A*.

The EF 300mm f/2.8 L IS has been out of production since the EF 300mm f/2.8 L IS II was introduced in 2011. As early as 2012 the ring was no longer available as a replacement part. Even third party knock-offs of the tripod ring have dried up by now.

Canon does still list the EF 300mm f/2.8 L IS on the list of lenses currently repaired by *Canon Professional Services*, but they may no longer fully support servicing the older version due to lack of parts availability.  If you're a member of *CPS* it couldn't hurt to give them a call.